# Proof verification of the theorem that integral domains have either $0$ or prime characteristic

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, positive-characteristic

I am doing Contemporary Abstract Algebra by Gallian and am stuck at the proof of the fact that integral domains have either $0$ or prime characteristic. The proof in the book goes as follows:

Let $R$ be an integral domain such that the additive order of $1$ is $n$. On the contrary, assume that $n$ is not prime and hence can be written as $n = s * t$ where, $1 \lt s, t \leq n $. Then $n \cdot 1 = (s* t) \cdot 1 = (s \cdot 1) (t \cdot 1) = 0$. Now since $R$ is an integral domain, one of these factors must be zero and hence we arrive at a contradiction.

But I then tried a different proof and can't seem to spot the mistake because my proof doesn't seem use the fact that $R$ is an integral domain and hence is giving the impression that any arbitrary ring with unity (at least) has either $0$ or prime characteristic. So, here goes my proof:

We have $n \cdot 1 = (s*t) \cdot 1 = \underbrace{(\underbrace{1+...+1}_{s\ times})+(\underbrace{1+...+1}_{s\ times})+\cdots+(\underbrace{1+...+1}_{s\ times})}_{t\ times}=0$.

Hence, we have $t \cdot (\underbrace{1+...+1}_{s\ times}) = t \cdot (s \cdot 1) = 0$. Now since $(s \cdot 1) \in R$ ($R$ is closed under addition), this is a contradiction to the fact that $n$ is the characteristic. Therefore, $(s \cdot 1) = 0$ which again is a contradiction to the fact that $n$ is the characteristic. Hence, $n$ must be a prime.

Now the thing is that nowhere in the proof did I use that $R$ is an integral domain and we could easily replace the integral domain condition with any arbitrary ring with unity.
I feel that I am missing some fundamental difference between the definition of the characteristic of an integral domain and that of any arbitrary ring but still haven't been able to figure out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See what happens when you apply your proof to $\mathbb{Z} / (4)$.

Comment: "Now since $(s\cdot 1)\in R$, this is a contradiction to the fact that $n$ is the characteristic". This phrase is not clear at all. How is $t(s1)=0$ a contradiction?

Comment: "Now the thing is that nowhere in the proof did I use that  is an integral domain"  How do you know $ts=0$ implies $s=0$ otherwise?

Comment: @Mark because n is the characteristic and hence is the smallest natural number for which na = 0 for all a in R.

Comment: The characteristic is the order of $1$ in the additive group. It doesn't mean it is the order of other elements as well. For example, take a look at the ring $\mathbb{Z_4}$. Its characteristic is clearly $4$, but $2+2=0$. So the order of the element $2$ is smaller than the characteristic.

Comment: @rschwieb here t is an integer, not an element of the ring. Moreover, in t(s1) = 0, the operation is not the same as that of the ring multiplication.

Comment: @Mark Bad enough that you copy my name, now you copy my example! But yes, the key here is that the characteristic is the smallest $n$ such that $\forall a \in R (n \cdot a = 0)$. OP has shown that $\exists a \in R (s \cdot a = 0)$, but that isn't a contradiction.

Comment: @Mark umm at the starting I assumed that R has some characteristic n. So by definition,  it should be the case that $n \cdot a = 0 \forall a \in R$. In your example of $\mathbb{Z_4}$, this ring doesn't even have a characteristic by your argument.

btw, I am using the definition given by wiki -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_(algebra)

Comment: @Singh_Gunjeet Sorry, I wasn't being clear. I should have stated that the characteristic is the smallest positive $n$ such that $\forall a \in R (\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n a = 0)$, if one exists; otherwise, 0. I used $n \cdot a$ as a shorthand for $\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n a$.

Comment: @MarkSaving yeah, i got that earlier also :)
but I am still confused like where do i need to use condition of integral domains in my proof?

Comment: @Singh_Gunjeet An equivalent definition of characteristic (the one you are using) states that $n$ is the smallest number such that all elements of the ring satisfy $na=0$. But it doesn't mean that some specific element $a\in R$ can't satisfy $ta=0$ for some $t<n$. It's just that if $t<n$ then not ALL elements satisfy $ta=0$. For example, the characteristic of $\mathbb{Z_4}$ is $4$, as for each $1\leq t<4$ there is some $a\in\mathbb{Z_4}$ such that $ta\ne 0$. So your proof doesn't work, as $t\cdot (s\cdot 1)=0$ does not imply $s\cdot 1=0$.

Comment: @Singh_Gunjeet the point is that $(t\cdot 1)(s\cdot 1)$ is a product of elements in the ring. I thought you already realized it but I guess not.  You cannot draw the conclusion that $s\cdot 1=0$ if “t is an integer” either.

Comment: ahh, so that is what i was overlooking!! thanks for clarifying :) @Mark

Comment: @rschwieb i realized that but I guess I misunderstood your comment and thought you were addressing my proof and not the book's. anyways, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is exactly the presence of zero divisors if the ring is not an integral domain. You might have $st \cdot 1 = 0$ with $s\cdot 1 \neq 0$ and $t\cdot 1 \neq 0$ (i.e. when $s\cdot 1$ and $t\cdot 1$ are zero divisors). Perhaps a simple counterexample can make it clearer. Consider $n\in \mathbb{N}$ a composite number (i.e. not prime), and look at the ring homomorphism $\varphi: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}, m\mapsto 1 + \cdots + 1 \ ( \ m \mathrm{ \ times})$. It is clear that the kernel is $n\mathbb{Z}$ and hence the characteristic is $n$, a composite number.